# SonarLint to Analyse PHP Code using Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, sonarlint

Has anyone tried to analyze the php code using sonarlint version 2.1 in eclipse?
Note: Eclipse version is Mars 4.5.2

Right now , using command prompt (Sonar Scanner - Php Plugin), we can scan the PHP code and able to see the dashboard  analysis report. However , using eclipse, we are able to bind the project to the SonarQube Server Instance but not able to perform code analysis.

Any suggestion on what could be the reason behind this issue.